# menu not created when fragment is created but works on resume

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, menu, layout-inflater

I have a fragment which displays a `mapview`.

I have to inflate a menu layout from the fragment and I have added `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in the code so that menu bar can inflated from the fragment.

But the interesting thing is that it doesn't show up when the fragment loads the first time. But if I switch over to some other fragment and comes back to this fragment the menu bar show up again. I have no idea why doesn't it show up in the first place.

What needs to be done ? Can some one help ?

The following is the content of the fragment layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the java class.

```
        public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter,
                GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

          @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView()");

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
            mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

            this.markers = new HashMap<>();
            this.activity = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();

            return rootView;
        }

     public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu()");
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            menu.clear();
                this.activity.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

        }

 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onMapReady");
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        try {
            if (checkScanPermissions()) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(getLocation(), 18));
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Permission to location not granted");
        }
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

        this.mMap = map;

        setUpMap(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState()");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume()");
        super.onResume();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mMapView.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried to remove menu.clear(); from onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: The print I have given in the function even doesn't come  'Log.i(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu()");' when I load it the first time. But will come when I resume the fragment from some other.

Answer (score 0):

This line:
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
is in the wrong method. Should be in onCreate instead.

add this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```